# Play Framework returning 404 with play.http.context and trailing slash

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a Play Framework application that serves an SPA. The routes file contains the following routes:

```
GET      /            controllers.Home.index
GET      /index.html  controllers.Home.index

# /api/* routes

GET      /*file       controllers.Assets.at(file)
```

`controllers.Home.index` serves the SPA's index after performing SSO routines.

When I run the application without any additional configuration, upon visiting `localhost:3000` and `localhost:3000/`, the `index` action in `Home` controller is invoked as expected.

The problems start when I configure `play.http.context`:

- When set to `/my-app`, requests to `localhost:3000/my-app` succeed; to `localhost:3000/my-app/` return 404.
- When set to `/my-app/`, requests to `localhost:3000/my-app` return 404; to `localhost:3000/my-app/` succeed.

Is there a way to configure Play such that requests to both URLs succeed with `controllers.Home.index`?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same, but there is no good answer. For Play/Akka those are 2 different URLs,

Option 1)
is to define it 2x

```
GET     /about                     controllers.HomeController.about
GET     /about/                     controllers.HomeController.about
```

Option 2)
redirect one url to another

```
GET /a                              controllers.HomeController.about
GET /a/                             controllers.Default.redirect(to = "/a")
```

Option 3)
more advanced ways, but I did not testd it

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/path-directives/ignoreTrailingSlash.html

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/path-directives/redirectToNoTrailingSlashIfPresent.html

https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/880

Comment: It doesn't work for the root URL (which is what this question is about) - I can't specify `//` for example

Answer (score -1):

Use both urls. With and without the trailing slash.

Comment: Please provide the correct answer. In this case may be the correct Urls will help,

Comment: What do you mean by "use both urls"? Use where? How should the configuration look like? How should the routes look like?